# Sharing a texture resource from DX11 to DX9 to WPF, need to wait for DeviceContext.Flush() to finish

Tags: directx, slimdx, wpf

I'm following these instructions on [TheCodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28526/Introduction-to-D3DImage) for rendering from DirectX to WPF using [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656710.aspx).

The trouble is that now that I have no swap chain to call Present() on -- which according to the article shouldn't be a problem, but it definitely wasn't copying my back buffer.

An additional step that I have to take before I can copy the texture to WPF is to share it with a second D3D9Ex device, since D3DImage only works with DX9 (which is understandable, as WPF is built on DX9). To that end, I've modified [some SlimDX code](https://code.google.com/p/shadercomposer/source/browse/trunk/Renderers/TerrainRenderer/SlimDX/SlimDXImage.cs?spec=svn3&r=3) to work with DirectX 11.

I tried calling `DeviceContext.Flush()` (the Immediate one) at the end of each render cycle, which kind of works -- most of the time it'll show my renderings, but maybe for maybe 3 or 4 out of 60 frames each second, it'll draw my clear color instead. This makes sense -- Flush() is non-blocking; it doesn't wait for the GPU to do its thing the way `SwapChain.Present` does.

Any idea what the proper solution is?

I have a feeling it has something to do with my texture parameters for the back buffer, but I don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
First:
// Create a Query to be able to wait for the completion of the drawing:
D3D11_QUERY_DESC qd;
ZeroMemory(&qd, sizeof(qd));
qd.Query = D3D11_QUERY_EVENT;
hr = m_U->m_pd3dDevice->CreateQuery(&qd, &m_U->m_pEventQuery);
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;
```

---

```
After the flush put the query in the queue (there is no call like begin in this case):
// Draw!
m_U->m_pImmediateContext->DrawInstanced( 3* numTrianglesPerInstance, numInstances, 0, 0);
m_U->m_pImmediateContext->Flush();
m_U->m_pImmediateContext->End(m_U->m_pEventQuery);
```

---

```
Wait for the paint/flush/query to end:
// wait for drawing to come to an end:
while (S_FALSE == m_U->m_pImmediateContext->GetData(m_U->m_pEventQuery, NULL /*&GPUfinished*/, 0 /*sizeof(GPUfinished)*/, 0));
```

---

```
Tidy up later:
if( m_U->m_pEventQuery) m_U->m_pEventQuery->Release();
```

Comment: Works, danke schoen!

Comment: You're suggesting a busy wait Greg. One should never busy wait!

Answer (score 4):

I think the proper way of syncronising the surfaces is using "[Direct3D9Ex and DXGI Shared Surface Queue](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/D3D9ExDXGISharedSurf)":

More info:

- in the docs for the queue,
- in chapter **Interoperability between Direct3D 9Ex and DXGI based APIs** here [Surface Sharing Between Windows Graphics APIs (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising too. All the better without a spinlock.